# What does /;/ and /^ +/ denote?

Tags: javascript, regex

I recently came across the statement :

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(/;/);
```

and

```
var pair = allCookies[i].split("=", 2);
if (pair[0].replace(/^ +/, "") == "lastvisit")
```

In the first statement what does `/;/` in the argument of split denote ?

In the second statement what does `/^ +/` in the argument of replace denote ?

Answer (score 7):

These are [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Javascript [supports them natively](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

In this particular example:

1. `.split(/;/)` uses `;` as the split character;
2. `.replace(/^ +/, "")` removes (`""`) any (`+`) leading (`^`) whitespace ().

In both examples, `/` surround or *delimit* the regular expression (or "regex"), informing Javascript that you're providing a regex.

Follow the links provided above for more information; regexes are broad in scope and worth learning.

Comment: why can't i just write `.split(";")`

Comment: @grassPro: You can. [`split` takes a string _or_ a regular expression.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: what different does `/;/` do then ?

Comment: @grassPro: Functionally, in this simple case, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Slashes delimit a regular expression, just like quotes delimit a string.

/;/ matches a semi-colon. Specifically:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(/;/);
```

Means we split the document.cookie string into an array, splitting it where there are semicolons. So it would take something like "a;b;c" and turn it into ["a", "b", "c"].

```
pair[0].replace(/^ +/, "")
```

Just strips all leading whitespace. It turns

```
"     lastvisit"
```

into

```
"lastvisit"
```

The caret ^ means "beginning of line", it's followed by space, and the + means to repeat the space one or more times, as many as possible.

Comment: As I said, slashes delimit a regular expression, just like a string is delimited with quotes. e.g. /regex/ vs. "string"

Comment: @grassPro: I told you two hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

The `//` syntax denotes a regular expression (also known as a 'regex').

Regex is a syntax for searching and replacing strings.

The first example you gave is `/;/`. This is a very simply regex which just searches the string for semi-colons, and then splits it into an array based on the result. Since this is not using any special regex functionality, it could just as easily have been expressed as a simple string, ie `split(";")` (as has been done with the equal sign in your other example), without making any difference to the result.

The second example is `/^ +/`. This is more complex and requires a bit of knowledge of how regex works. In short, what it is doing is searching for leading spaces on a string, and removing them.

To learn more about regex, I recommend this site as a good starting point: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

I think that /^ +/ means: one or more no-" " characters

Comment: ^ means not only in the context of a range `[]`, if it is in the beginning of the regular expression, it means the beginning of a line